# Can I debug a Railo CFML app with JDebugTool?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, railo, cfml

Can anyone attest to debugging a CFML application on Railo with [JDebugTool](http://www.debugtools.com/index.html)? I'm stuck with CF8 and Eclipse plugin for dev setup. So all debug gets done with dumps and aborts and there are times when I REALLY REALLY miss proper debug tool.

Comment: What does _"I'm stuck with CF8 and Eclipse plugin for dev setup."_ mean - what's stopping you using Railo on dev? :/

Comment: That makes no sense. You can run Railo/Resin locally and forget about CF8 for this.

Comment: CFML, Railo/Resin and Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [Fusion Debug](http://www.fusion-debug.com/fd/) if you like. Works like a charm with Railo.

Gert

Answer (score 2):

I've not used JDebugTool, but ColdFusion 8+ does have a built in debugger you can use in Eclipse. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/debugger.html

Comment: ... I"m stuck with Railo however, no choice on that.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect that, otherwise people will assume you're on Adobe ColdFusion 8.

Comment: You're welcome, but I wouldn't mark my answer as the accepted one, since you still don't have an answer as to how to use JDebugTool. Were I in your shoes, I'd unaccept the answer (if you can) and wait for someone to come around to helping you with Railo.

Comment: ... I guess I could wait. Unfortunately so few people look at CF questions anyway and I've been looking for a solution for a while now. Just came across that debugger again today and got my hopes up :-)